# Hide or show sub Gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject which contains a C# class component.

This gameobject has 4 sub gameobjects which contains png images.
Each of this gameobject has a name in hierarchy window.

I want to hide or show each image from my C# class.

I have tried to do this in Update method:

```
my_sub_gameobject_name.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
```

or

```
my_sub_gameobject_name.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```

But my_sub_gameobject_name is not recognize by C# compiler...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access gameobject by name, you can use [GameObject.Find()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html).

`GameObject.Find("your_gameobject_name").GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;`

Note that this is a costly operation and you should avoid calling it repeatedly in Update().

Comment: OP said "sub" which I think he means these are children of another GameObject. In this case, it will be better to find the parent object first and store it in a temporary variable in the `Start` function then use `parent.transform.Find` to find the child instead of `GameObject.Find`

Comment: If they're pre-existing GameObjects in the scene then I'd recommend setting up `public GameObject your_gameobject_name;` in the script and setting them in the inspector.